# Returned image from Camera error on fileDescriptors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-bitmap

I want to open Camera and save image as bitmap after photo is taken. I've found solution, but part of it doesn't work properly.

Do anyone know what can cause this exception?

`getImageFromResult()` is called inside `onActivityResult`.
Result code is result code returned from Camera intent and `ImageReturnedIntent` is data(image).

Exception: `fileDescriptorErr: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) (decodeBitmap)`

Code:

```
fun getImageFromResult(
        context: Context, resultCode: Int,
        imageReturnedIntent: Intent?
    ): Bitmap? {
        var bm: Bitmap? = null
        val imageFile = getTempFile(context)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedImage: Uri?
            val isCamera = imageReturnedIntent == null ||
                    imageReturnedIntent.data == null ||
                    imageReturnedIntent.data == Uri.fromFile(imageFile)
            if (isCamera) {
                /** CAMERA  */
                selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile)
            } else {
                /** ALBUM  */
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent!!.data
            }
            selectedPhotoName = selectedImage.toString()

            bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage)
            val rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, isCamera)
            bm = rotate(bm, rotation)
        }
        return bm
    }

    /**
         * Resize to avoid using too much memory loading big images (e.g.: 4096 × 2160)
         */
        private fun getImageResized(context: Context, selectedImage: Uri): Bitmap {
            var bm: Bitmap
            val sampleSizes = intArrayOf(5, 3, 2, 1)
            var i = 0
            do {
                bm = decodeBitmap(context, selectedImage, sampleSizes[i])
                i++
            } while (bm.width < DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY && i < sampleSizes.size)
            return bm
        }

        private fun decodeBitmap(context: Context, theUri: Uri, sampleSize: Int): Bitmap {
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inSampleSize = sampleSize

            var fileDescriptor: AssetFileDescriptor? = null
            try {
                fileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri, "r")

            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                App.log("CameraPhoto: fileDescriptorErr: ${e.message} (decodeBitmap) ")
            }

            val actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
                fileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor, null, options
            )

            return actuallyUsableBitmap
        }
```

Comment: Where is `selectedImage` coming from? What is its value?

Comment: Are you using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`? If so, how does the user's chosen camera app know about `getTempFile()`? Why would an image wind up there? Are you using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` for that? If so, does `getTempFile()` return the same value on every call? Because, if not, then the camera app will have been told to save in one file, and you are looking in a different one.